# How to use ShowDialog and make a form MDI child to another form

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've been trying to do this for a while, and all the result i got on the research i did were all for c#.

I have a main form, that is MDI and all the forms are MDI childs to this form. The thing is, whenever i use ShowDialog on a child form to any other form, like a consulting window where the user chooses a value, then passes it to a textbox or combobox in the parent form, it won't let me set that Child form as MDI child to that main form.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're looking for is [here, in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/7aw8zc76(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). You can choose at the top right of the page if you want c# or VB code.

Just in case this page disappears or something, here's the relevant code:

```
Protected Sub MDIChildNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItem2.Click
   Dim NewMDIChild As New Form2()
   'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
   NewMDIChild.MdiParent = Me
   'Display the new form.
   NewMDIChild.Show()
End Sub
```

Have fun!

Comment: With the other solution you gave me in the other thread, form2.show() won't let me pass the value between forms, but i can select form2.mdiparent = form_main. If i do form2.showdialog, i can pass values between forms, but i can't select form2.mdiparent = form_main. My question is if there's a way to do this using show dialog.

Comment: I was able to figure out a way to do this. I used form2.ShowDialog(Form1) as I read in another thread that if I do it like this I can then set CenterParent on Form2 properties and it will be inside of Form1.